# sed: Bad flag in substitute command '('

Tags: shell, sed

I'm trying to replace a placeholder ${SNIPPET} with the content of a js file. I struggle to understand the error I receive though.

```
sed  -e "s/\${SNIPPET}/$(cat snippet.js)/" ../../handlebars/templates/bootstrap-template.hbs
```

Error: bad flag in substitute command: '('

Looking for a solution that could work cross-platform (OSX/Linux)

Comment: You'll need to escape slashes in the js file.

Comment: are you suggesting to replace cat snippet.js with some sed to replace slashes with escape slash ?

Comment: Without knowing the value of `$SNIPPET` or the contents of `snippet.js`, it's all going to be guesswork...  But it might be the same problem as described in [Replace a word with multiple lines using sed?](/q/10107459) or any of its linked duplicates.

Comment: there is no $SNIPPET variable. there is a placeholder string '${SNIPPET}'. snippet.js is as the suffix .js suggests a javascript file and it has to be considered to contains all possible characters you may have in a js file. I tried solutions to remove newlines but didn't work @glennjackman was actually right pointing to slashes as the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using these test files

```
$ cat snippet.js
hello/(world)
$ cat template.hbs
foo
${SNIPPET}
bar
```

I can (kind of) replicate your error (I have GNU sed 4.2.2):

```
$ sed "s/\${SNIPPET}/$(cat snippet.js)/" template.hbs
sed: -e expression #1, char 20: unknown option to `s'
```

You can do this, which escapes slashes (which are the delimiter for the `s///` command)

```
sed "s/\${SNIPPET}/$(sed 's,/,\\/,g' snippet.js)/" template.hbs
```

```
foo
hello/(world)
bar
```

Or, if the SNIPPET placeholder is on its own line like I have it, you can use other sed commands:

```
sed '/\${SNIPPET}/{
    # read the file into the stream
    r snippet.js
    # delete SNIPPET line
    d
}' template.hbs
```

```
foo
hello/(world)
bar
```

---

Yet another approach

```
j=$(<snippet.js)   # read the file: `$(<...)` is a bash builtin for `$(cat ...)`
sed "s/\${SNIPPET}/${j//\//\\\/}/" template.hbs
```